# PHP array foreach and display all values that match a pattern

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm using scandir to get a list of all of the access logs in the logs directory and can display the different months of access logs if the `$access_log` = certain criteria which is based on domain and month.

What I want to do is simplify this code so I don't have to write out all of these if statements and month variables.

For instance if there are 100 access logs for each domain I'd have to write out all these if statements 100 times.

An access log looks like this `subdomain.mydomain.com-Jan-2016.gz`.

So I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite my code to have only 1 if statement that looks for a pattern of a `$domain` in the `$access_log` and lists those access logs in the `$log_month` variable. So far can't figure it out unless I write a separate if statement for each `$log_month` variable as you can see below in the 3 if statement examples within the foreach loop.

```
$access_logs = scandir($log_list);

$month = date("M-Y");
$prevmonth = date('M-Y', strtotime("first day of last month"));
$minus_2_month = date('M-Y', strtotime("first day of -2 month"));
$minus_3_month = date('M-Y', strtotime("first day of -3 month"));
$minus_4_month = date('M-Y', strtotime("first day of -4 month"));
//etc etc etc

    foreach($access_logs as $access_log) {

            if ($access_log == $domain_dashes . '.mydomain.com-' . $month . '.gz') {
                $log_month = '<li><a href="logs.php?log=' . $access_log . '">' . $access_log . '</a></li>' . "\n            ";
            }

            if ($access_log == $domain_dashes . '.mydomain.com-' . $prevmonth . '.gz') {
                $log_month .= '<li><a href="logs.php?log=' . $access_log . '">' . $access_log . '</a></li>' . "\n            ";
            }

            if ($access_log == $domain_dashes . '.mydomain.com-' . $minus_2_month . '.gz') {
                $log_month .= '<li><a href="logs.php?log=' . $access_log . '">' . $access_log . '</a></li>' . "\n            ";
            }

           // etc etc etc
    }
```

**Update Jan 19 2016**

To be more specific, this is what I need. A list of domains with the access logs next to each domain.

**Domain 1 - domain1.com-jan-2016.gz | domain1.com-dec-2015.gz**

**Domain 2 - domain2.com-jan-2016.gz**

**Domain 3 - domain3.com-jan-2016.gz | domain3.com-dec-2015.gz | etc | etc**

etc

etc

next to each domain I need it to display the access log files. For domain 1 there might be 2 or 3 files from various months. For domain 2 there might be only 1 file. For domain 3 there might be a dozen.

The way I have my code above works for what I need. But I wanted to condense the code with || or one simple if statement, but when I do that, then not all the access logs get displayed next to each domain. Only one file will get displayed.

How do I get all the access log files next to each domain name with a condensed version of my code above?

Comment: Inside each if block you are doing same thing.So why if blocks?

Comment: You can concatenate the three ifs with OR

Comment: if I concatenate the three ifs with an OR then only the first $access_log is satisfied and all the rest get ignored and won't get displayed on screen. For instance, if domain of abc.com has 3 access logs, only 1 of them will get displayed and the other 2 left out.

Comment: I don't see how array_map will work. I have a list of access logs. I have a list of domains. I'm trying to match the domains to the access logs. But some domains have 2 or 3 access logs of the past few months. How can I output all access logs that have the domain as part of the access log string?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I skimmed the question too quickly. `array_map` would help with mapping each logfile to the output string, but you'd still need the callback to do your filtering. if the prefix is always the same, then maybe `if ( 0 === strpos($access_log, $domain_dashes . 'mydomain.com-') ) {` will do the trick.

Comment: @Duncan no that did not work. through everything off.

Comment: It may need some modifications. But `0 === strpos` should match everything beginning a particular prefix. Otherwise, if you need to be fancier, you'd need a regex.

Comment: I'm sure it matches, but it won't display everything for each domain.

Comment: just updated my question Update Jan 19 2016. Maybe now with that you can understand more fully what's going on and how to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP **[glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)** function instead of using scandir.
With glob you can get pathnames by a pattern.

For example:

```php
$access_logs = glob('*.mydomain.com-*.gz');
$log_month = '';
foreach($access_logs as $access_log) {
    $log_month .= '<li><a href="logs.php?log=' . $access_log . '">' . $access_log . '</a></li>' . "\n            ";
}
```

**Update Jan 19 2016**

I recommend to use regex to split the infomation (domain, month, year) from the filename. To collect all log files per domain you can use the domain as array key.
After gathering you have to loop through all domains and you can list all corresponding log files.

```php
<?php

# gathering
$access_logs = glob('*.gz');

$domainList = [];
foreach ($access_logs as $access_log) {
    if (preg_match('/((?:[-A-Za-z0-9]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6})-(\w{3})-(\d{4})/i', $access_log, $matches)) {
        $domain = $matches[1];
        # $month = $matches[2];
        # $year = $matches[3];
        if (!isset($domainList[$domain])) {
            $domainList[$domain] = '';
        }
        $domainList[$domain] .= '<li><a href="logs.php?log=' . $access_log . '">' . $access_log . '</a></li>';
    }
}

# output
foreach ($domainList as $domain => $list) {
    echo "<h1>{$domain}</h1>";
    echo "<ul>{$list}</ul>";
}
```

You can adjust the output by your own. But the logic do what you want.

Comment: this does not get me any different values as scandir does for this particular project. I'm still running into the problem of the foreach looping and only outputting 1 access log per domain name even if more access logs are in the list.

Comment: just updated my question Update Jan 19 2016. Maybe now with that you can understand more fully what's going on and how to help.